# htaccess remove trailing slash in zend framework on localhost

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I can't seem to get the following htaccess rule to work correctly with Zend Framework.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above code will convert `localhost/zendtest/dev/public/login/` to `localhost/login`, it removes the slash at the end, but looses everything else.

How to I get it to convert `localhost/zendtest/dev/public/login/` to `localhost/zendtest/dev/public/login`

I want to simply remove the slash at the end.

Comment: just move `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]` to line 6.You don't need line : `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]` .

Answer (score 0):

The trailing `/` is usually something that is automatically appended when it has determined that the path is a directory. Normally you can make it stop adding the `/` using this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

However, that will only prevent the system from automatically appending them. A user could still type it in manually if they wanted too. I would suggest just detecting it with your pre-processor and removing the `/` if it's the last character in the file path, rather than using rewrites. Certainly don't use a redirect because then you're using an extra HTTP connection merely for the purpose of removing a `/`, what a waste of resources.